# How to pass python dataFrame with field name as variable to user defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe, DataFrame1: LocationListExport - Columns: ['CountryCode', 'Country Name']
Dataframe2: Location - Columns: ['Code', 'Name']

I want to find the LocationListExport['CountryCode'] which is not present in Location['Code']

My Function:

```
def checkDimensionListItems(dataDL, dDLdimensionCode, knoxDimensionWithCode):
newDimensionItemAdded = dataDL[~dataDL[dDLdimensionCode].isin(knoxDimensionWithCode)][dDLdimensionCode].unique()
return newDimensionItemAdded
```

Calling Function:

```
checkDimensionListItems(LocationListExport, 'CountryCode', 'Location.Code')
```

**Error Occurs: AttributeError: TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]**

Below script works fine without function, But I want update for many dataframe.

```
LocationListExport[~LocationListExport.CountryCode.isin(Location.Code)].CountryCode.unique()
```

Can we do this using user defined function.

Comment: Looks quite simple but this would be much easier if you shared sample code with us, e.g. **df.head().to_dict()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 2 variable for DF & Field as below:

```
def checkDimensionListItems(dataDL, dDLdimensionCode, knoxDimension, knoxDimensionCode):
newDimensionItemAdded = dataDL[~dataDL[dDLdimensionCode].isin(knoxDimension[knoxDimensionCode])]

return newDimensionItemAdded
```

checkDimensionListItems(LocationListExport, 'Country Code', Location, 'Code')